# Ubuntu server PDO

Tags: 18.04, php, php7

I have Ubuntu server 18.04 with PHP7.2 and PHP5.6 loaded.

When using PHP7.2 the PDO drivers shows in phpinfo().

When using PHP5.6 the PDO driver does not show in phpinfo().

The php.ini files look pretty much the same.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Extensions are not loaded in php.ini, there are some directories to look into.
For example, look into `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d` for a list of extensions loaded in php cli. Similar directories are present for apache and fpm (and, of course, for other versions of php)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. All sorted now